# Obtaining scaled Fourier restriction estimate

Tags: harmonic-analysis

I have a restriction estimate:
\begin{equation}
\| \widehat{f\,d\sigma}\|_{L^2(V)} \le C\|V\|_{\mathcal{L}^{2,p}}^{1/2} \| f \|_{L^2(\mathbb{S}^{n-1})}.
\end{equation}
where $V$ is a positive function which is in Fefferman-Phong class $\mathcal{L}^{2,p}$(not important, I think), $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$ denotes a unit sphere and $d\sigma$ is Lesbegue measure on unit sphere $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$. Moreover,
$$\widehat{f\,d\sigma}(x)=\int_{\mathbb{S}^{n-1}} e^{-ix\cdot\xi} f(\xi) \, d\sigma.$$
Now, I want to scale it to radius $r$. That is, I want to get
\begin{equation}
\| \widehat{f\,d\sigma_{r}}\|_{L^2(V)} \le C r^{\alpha} \|V\|_{\mathcal{L}^{2,p}}^{1/2}\|f\|_{L^2(\mathbb{S}_{r}^{n-1} ) }.
\end{equation}
where $\mathbb{S}_r^{n-1}$ denotes a sphere of radius $r$ and $\sigma_r$ is its measure and $\alpha$ is some number derived by scaling.

I guess the $\alpha=1$ since it makes sense to solve a problem.
How can I calculate it?